# How to achieve animated splashscreen in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Im new to Nativescript , please guide me on how i can achieve this type of splash transition in native script .

the link to app is below

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.examples&hl=en

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that page you've linked to is a link to the source code: http://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-marketplace-demo

If you can't find it there you can open an issue on their repo.